# Не случайное меньшее число

Tags: php

Есть диапазон числ от 1 до 10000, нужно преобразовать случайное число из диапазона в числа от 0 до 6. Операция должна быть повторима, т.е. вызывам my_function(754), получаем 3, повторный вызов должен выдать вновь 3. Ну и максимально равномерно распределять использование чисел 0-6 среди 1-10000. Извиняюсь за плохую формулировку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой вариант -

```
function my_func($num){
  return $num%7;
}
```

Распределение идеальное.

Чуть сложнее - домножить его на какое-нибудь простое число, а потом взять по модулю 7.

```
function my_func($num){
  return 2711*$num%7;
}
```

**Обновление**

Я даже рискну предположить, что число, на которое мы домножаем (2711 в примере), достаточно представить взаимно-простым с 7, но гарантировать не могу: математику подзабыл уже. Поэтому используйте простое, оно не нарушит распределения.

Comment: Спасибо, как раз хотел отписать, нашел. =)

Comment: Я даже рискну предположить, что число, на которое мы домножаем(2711 в примере) достаточно представить взаимно-простым с 7, но гарантировать не могу: математику подзабыл уже. Поэтому используйте простое, оно не нарушит распределения.

Comment: @knes, целочисленного остатка от деления более чем достаточно оказалось ;)